# Trying to fill polygon fills the entire map

Tags: shapefile, style, mapserver

I have been given some shp files to be displayed using Mapserver. Until now I was able to find the correct projections, display the map, and show labels. However, I have problems with polygon colors. When I set COLOR to any value, the entire map is filled with that color.

Is it a problem with the shp file, or what am I doing wrong?

For example:

```
LAYER
    NAME mylayer
    TYPE POLYGON    
    DATA "mylayer.shp"
    STATUS DEFAULT
    CLASS
      NAME mylayer

      STYLE
        COLOR 255 0 0
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
      END
    END
  END
```

This will fill the entire map with red color, polygons have black outline.

Comment: Do the full map get orange if you change COLOR to 255 173 15?

Comment: Yes, it turns all orange with black polygon outlines.

Comment: Have you checked the polygon file in some desktop GIS? Maybe there is one big polygon.

Comment: donut polygons or multi-part polygons in your shapefile?

Comment: It sounds like you are symbolizing your polygons correctly.  Does the data look like you expect it to (features in the right place at the correct scale)?  What do you expect to see?  Is it that you only want to color specific polygons?

Comment: This is a cadastrial map, and I would like to fill the buildings. But I have tried to put this shp file into ArcGIS explorer, and it renders it the same way (if I choose to fill polygons, it fills the entire map). So I guess it's the original file that has problems, not Mapserver...

Comment: Often with parcels, you will have contiguous polygons that cover an entire area.  If there are individual polygons for the buildings and there is a code to indicate which polys represent buildings, you can use an expression in your MapServer layer class to symbolize the buildings in a specific way.  Can you post a small data sample anywhere?

Comment: I could post a small data sample, but I am a real newbie, and I don't exactly know how to extract a sample from a shp file :) I am just displaying them... Which tool could I use?

Answer (score 2):

In your layer config you have one class (and one colour), so you are telling MapServer to render all polygons with one colour.

If you want to have diffent coloured polygons you need to specify more than one class (each with a different colour).

So you need to find the coloumn in your mylayer.shp that holds information you want to classify (colour) your map on; for example it could be be called *landuse*, then for each unique value of that column that you want to show you need your own CLASS, so your config file might end up looking like:

```
LAYER
  NAME mylayer
  TYPE POLYGON    
  DATA "mylayer.shp"
  STATUS DEFAULT

  CLASSITEM "landuse"

  CLASS
    NAME "big building"
    STYLE
      COLOR 255 0 0
      OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    END
  END

  CLASS
    NAME "small building"
    STYLE
      COLOR 0 255 0 
      OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    END
  END

  CLASS
    NAME "no building"
    STYLE
      COLOR 0 0 255
      OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    END
  END

END
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has a similar issue, this might help:

I had to modify my `CLASS` definitions in the Mapfile to include `EXPRESSION`, as follows.

```
CLASS
    EXPRESSION {<label>}
    NAME "<label>"
    STYLE
        COLOR 255 0 0 
        OPACITY 0.8
    END
END
```

I don't think this should be required, but in my case it was.